# Blazor 7 Virtualize - How to synch up 2 Virtualize components

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have an implementation of the Virtualize component and it works rather well. That is, until there is too much going on. Meaning either too may rows or perhaps too may columns. The data we need to show is rather dynamic but can be summarized by X number of Tests where we have a Test Header row and then Y number of Test Measurements beneath that Test.

After numerous iterations of normal HTML and trying different ways of coding it to be as streamlined as possible, I have come up with the following:

What I have created appears to be a table that has some fixed columns on the left and then any number of (horizontally) scrollable columns on the right. Of course the entire table can be vertically scrolled for as many rows that the data requires. The backing data is a `List` of what I am calling a `VirtualizedRow` which has some properties for styling and row type and most specifically, `List<VirtualizedCell> FixedCells` and `List<VirtualizedCell> OtherCells`.

In the HTML, I actually have two `table` elements, one for the `FixedCells` and another for the `OtherCells`. This works great! With both of these `table`'s, just inside the `tbody` element, I have an `Virtualize` component. They are both setup exactly the same (except the `@ref` attribute) so they call the same methods and/or have the same base data.

```
<div id="sync-associate-pcs-fixed" class="associate-pc-fixed">
  <table class="table table-fixed" tabindex="-1">
    <thead class="sticky-top">
      ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <Virtualize @ref="RowsVirtualizerFixed" Items="VisibleRows" OverscanCount="5" Context="row" ItemSize="RowHeight">
        ...
```

And the right-side of the table (OtherCells):

```
<div id="sync-associate-pcs-scroller" sync-scroll-with="sync-associate-pcs-fixed" class="associate-pc-scrolling">
  <table class="table table-fixed" tabindex="-1">
    <thead class="sticky-top">
      ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <Virtualize @ref="RowsVirtualizer" Items="VisibleRows" OverscanCount="5" Context="row" ItemSize="RowHeight">
        ...
```

I have done both the `Items` and `ItemsProvider` properties and both seem to produce the same result. I have all of the data in memory anyway, so lazy loading is not needed.

In the `OnAfterRender` event, I hook up some javascript.

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollSyncer", "sync-associate-pcs-scroller");
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function scrollSyncer(scrollerId) {
  var scroller = document.getElementById(scrollerId);

  if (scroller) {
    scroller.addEventListener("scroll", doScrollSync);
  }
}

function doScrollSync(e) {
  let fixed = document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("sync-scroll-with"));

  fixed.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
  fixed.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft;
}
```

What this javascript does is allows you to scroll on the right-side table and it mirrors the `scrollTop` position of the right-side table over to the left-side table.

As I have said, this works great 95% of the time. Every now and then, it gets out of sync. So now rows are no longer horizontally aligned. Sometimes, we can scroll up or down a "page" worth of data so the `Virtualizer`'s can refresh and things get back in sync. But this does not always work, so I have been trying to figure out a way to force this to occur.

I have tried to `debounce` the `doScrollSync` method but that just made it laggy and actually didn't fix the issue.

I have tried to refresh the `Virtualizer`'s and that did nothing:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
  RowsVirtualizer.RefreshDataAsync(),
  RowsVirtualizerLeft.RefreshDataAsync()
);
StateHasChanged();
```

Elsewhere on this page, I have what I call a `VirtualizedJump` which allows you to click from a list of Test names and that will scroll you down to that Test within the grid, even if it is not rendered as if it was 1000 lines below. In case it helps, here is that code:

```
public async Task VirtualizedJump(string recordId)
{
  var entry = Records.Where(x => x.Id == $"test-{recordId}").FirstOrDefault();
  var visibleRecordsCount = FilteredRows.Count;
  var index = FilteredRows
    .Where(x => x.IsVisible == true)
    .ToList()
    .IndexOf(entry);
  var position = (double)index / visibleRecordsCount;
  var offsetPosition = (visibleRecordsCount * RowHeight) * position;

  // The RowHeight * 4 is to take off the top four header rows
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToVirtualizedElement", "sync-associate-pcs-scroller", offsetPosition - (RowHeight * 4));
}
```

To see if this would help, I would click one of these Test links to Jump to it, and that does not work.

As near as I can tell, the scroll position (`scrollTop`) is correctly getting mirrored because I can log before and after values and what it should be and they match. This tells me that the `Virtualize` components `Items` are not syncing up. One would think calling the `RefreshDataAsync` method would take care of it, but it does not.

So I switched back to the `ItemsProvider` event so I could log some information. I even made a copy of the `RowsLoader` method so I can log the same information from each side and see what is different.

```
public async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<VirtualizedRow>> RowsLoader(ItemsProviderRequest request)
{
  var result = await ValueTask.FromResult(new ItemsProviderResult<VirtualizedRow>(
    VisibleRows
      .Skip(request.StartIndex)
      .Take(request.Count),
      VisibleRows.Count()
  ));

  System.Console.WriteLine($"Rght: {request.StartIndex,-3} {request.Count,-2} = {result.Items.First().Key}");

  return result;
}
```

The only difference is the other one says "Left:".

I got some strange behavior. Most of the time the `request.Count` was the same (38) but other times it was 37 or 36. That `Key` property is something I have on the `VirtualizedRow` that is just an Id if you will and is the rows number, so that "should" be the same if the `Virtualize`ers are in sync.

When I use the jump link, this is what I get and would expect:

```
Rght: 66  38 = 71
Left: 66  38 = 71
```

I scrolled for a bit and it eventually gets out of sync. It (appeared) to possibly get out of sync but then catch up a few times. I attribute this to the times when `Left` was logged more than once in a row.

```
Rght: 66  38 = 71
Left: 66  38 = 71
Rght: 72  38 = 77
Left: 72  38 = 77
Rght: 78  38 = 83
Left: 78  38 = 83
Rght: 85  38 = 90
Left: 85  38 = 90
Rght: 93  38 = 98
Left: 93  38 = 98
Rght: 101 38 = 106
Left: 101 38 = 106
Rght: 107 38 = 112
Left: 107 38 = 112
Rght: 116 38 = 121
Left: 126 36 = 131
Left: 119 38 = 124
Rght: 122 38 = 127
Left: 126 38 = 131
Rght: 128 38 = 133
Left: 132 38 = 137
Rght: 135 38 = 140
Rght: 145 38 = 150
Left: 140 38 = 145
Left: 146 38 = 151
Rght: 154 38 = 159
Left: 160 36 = 165
Left: 146 36 = 151
```

Something odd with the `Take / request.Count` is that when it is not 38, that seems to only happen with the Left one. I have seen it as low as 35 but never more then 38. So I think this `Take` is perhaps the issue. Whatever is "providing" that `ItemsProviderRequest` request is not consistent. As I last ditch effort, I forced the count to 38 for both and it seemed better but eventually did get out of sync.

So, if there is a way to sync up 2 `Virtualize` components, that would be great.

Comment: [Facetious] I'm afraid I got lost on page 50, line 17......  If what you are trying to do is to set the scroll position of a Virtualize component, I don't think it can be done.  A similar scenario is coming back to a page after showing say row 365 on a view page, and having the virtualize component run down to the same pane [showing row 365] you were displaying when you left.???

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis what you describe is actually my VirtualizedJump.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible with the standard Virtualize component.

*Why?*  The current position of the virtualized view i.e. the `StartIndex` and `Count` values are internal to `Virtualize`.  There's no setters.

If you provide a full list to `Items`, it internalizes getting the view dataset from the full list.  You can't set the `StartIndex`.

If you provide a delegate to `ItemsProvider`, your delegate gets a   `ItemsProviderRequest` that provides the internal `StartIndex` and `Count` values the component is maintaining.  Overriding the StartIndex in the request with your value doesn't solve the problem.  You don't set the internal value to your value when you return the `ItemsProviderResult`.  That just contains the dataset the component requested and the total count [so it knows how far to "page" and how big a right side slider to show].  You just have a view that out of sync with the data.

You need to pick apart the Virtualize code and write your own version.  The code is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web/src/Virtualizationhttps://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web/src/Virtualization

Comment: Thank you for the info and link, I will go down that rabbit hole and report back!